# Splitting a three phase contactor

Tags: power-supply, relay, mains

I want to power two heating strips. I have available to me a three phase contactor to pull power, which is activated by a temperature controller. I am hoping to split this power into two single phases to power two heating strips. The contactor itself definitely receives power and emits a large clicking noise. [image]

However, my heating strips do not appear to be drawing power. I am unfamiliar with contactor setup schemes. I currently have the relay segment of my temperature controller connected to the power in of the contactor (denoted by connections A and B). Meanwhile, [heater strip](https://www.mcmaster.com/#3605K55) 1 is connected to C and D, and 2 is connected to E and F.

Do I need to bridge the middle connection to draw power from the contactor, or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: (1) Please add a schematic of your setup. There's a button on the editor toolbar and it's very easy to use. Show the supply and the load connections. (2) Your terminology is a little off. You don't use a contactor to "pull" power. You use it to switch or control power. (3) Have you wired both ends of heater strip 1 to C and D? (That's not how it's done.)

Comment: 1) yes, that is fine. I will do so. 2) Ok, the contactor does correctly switch on and off as desired 3) No. I have wired one end of the heater to C and the other to D.

Comment: The power for the heaters should be connected to the "L" terminals of the contactor, with the corresponding "T" terminals connected to the "Hot" or "Line" side of the heaters.  The other side of the heaters should be connected directly to Neutral.  The contactor only switches the incoming power - it does not produce power.  The power you apply to the "A" and "B" terminals just moves the switch contacts in the contactor - it is not passed on to the load.

Comment: You should think of a relay or contactor as an electrically-operated switch.  There is no electrical connection between the coil that moves the switch (your A and B terminals) and the switch contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contactor is not a power source and does not generate electricity. It is simply a set of switch contacts operated by an electro-magnet coil. Your circuit just connects the ends of the heaters to each other when the coil is energised.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwbm4Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Correct wiring of system.*

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. I am learning one day at a time.